# Dockerfile : Install packages to run python3 script

Tags: python, docker

I'm new to Docker (Community Edition) and currently trying to create a Dockerfile to run my python3 script but I'm encountering a problem when I try to build the image

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

COPY . /

RUN \
apt-get update \
apt-get install python3-pip \
pip3 install bs4 \
pip3 install requests \
apt-get install python3-lxml -y \
pip3 install Pillow \
apt-get install libopenjp2-7 -y \
apt-get install libtiff5 -y

CMD [ "python3","./Manga-Alert.py" ]
```

But I'm getting an error, he doesn't find the package python3-pip
And then fails completely:

[image]

I'm probably writing my Dockerfile wrongly but I don't know how to resolve my problem.

Comment: As far as i know, the python:3 image comes with a pip, so you don't have to install `python3-pip`, and you should use it as `pip` not `pip3`. It is also better to [freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/#pip-freeze) your requirements to `requirements.txt`  file and use `pip install -r requirements.txt` instead of installing them one by one.

Comment: Yeah I saw a lot of people doing like this, I should also do it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Those slashes just mean new line in the docker file. It isn't the same as running the commands on the terminal. Because of this you need to separate each command with an && if you want them all to execute under one RUN direction.

```
FROM python:3

COPY . /

RUN \
apt-get update -y && \
apt-get install python3-pip -y && \
pip3 install bs4 && \
pip3 install requests && \
apt-get install python3-lxml -y && \
pip3 install Pillow && \
apt-get install libopenjp2-7 -y && \
apt-get install libtiff5 -y

CMD [ "python3","./Manga-Alert.py" ]
```